# Issue while installing docker based Solr 9.2

Tags: docker-compose, solr

I am trying to install solr9.2.0. I was using solr 8.9. I updated the docker compose file with the solr version and tried to install. But I am getting following error.
The currently defined **JAVA_HOME** (`/opt/java/openjdk`) refers
to a location where Java could not be found.  Aborting.
Either fix the **JAVA_HOME** variable or remove it from the
environment so that the system **PATH** will be searched.

Then i tried to set java home to 11 in the server and tried to run , it does not work. Then I tried to add SOLR_JAVA_HOME parameter in the compose file and run , still no success.
My compose file

```
#
# inspired from: https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr-examples/blob/master/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml
#
version: '3.7'
services:
  solr1:
    image: solr:9.2.1
    container_name: solr1
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    environment:
      ZK_HOST: "zoo1:2181"
      SOLR_JAVA_MEM: "-Xms512m -Xmx2g"
      SOLR_HOST: "linux10"
    networks:
      - solr
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
    command: solr -f -cloud
    volumes:
      - solr1-data:/var/solr
 
  solr2:
    image: solr:9.2.1
    container_name: solr2
    ports:
     - "7574:7574"
    environment:
      ZK_HOST: "zoo1:2181"
      SOLR_JAVA_MEM: "-Xms512m -Xmx2g"
      SOLR_HOST: "linux10"     
    networks:
      - solr
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
    command: solr -f -cloud -p 7574
    volumes:
      - solr2-data:/var/solr

  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper:3.6.3
    container_name: zoo1
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - 9983:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181
      ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST: mntr, conf, ruok
    networks:
      - solr
    volumes:
      - zoo1-data:/data
      - zoo1-datalog:/datalog 

networks:
  solr:

volumes:
  zoo1-data:
  zoo1-datalog:
  solr1-data:
  solr2-data:
```

Tried to set java home to 11 and run , but it did not work

Comment: Correct your JAVA_HOME path. Give path till your/jdk/path/ and inside it you find bin/java. 
If it still not work. Add it in your solr.in.sh file JAVA_HOME variable.

Comment: I got the issue. Docker based solr comes with java . I installed latest version of docker and it works. Solr 9 needs docker 20.10.10 or newer.